# I see a warning about a potential question ban on meta.stackexchange, but I don't think I have any downvoted posts on meta.SE!

Tags: discussion, meta, post-ban

When I came to post (about an unrelated SSL cert bug that turns out to be a duplicate), I saw a warning about a potential question ban on meta.SE.

I seem to have three questions on meta.SE, all with positive scores.

Why is this, and do I need to worry?

I am banned from asking questions on programmers.SE.

Comment: Now it seems that you do (not because of me). Have you checked "deleted recent questions" in your profile, [Questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/246182/demetri?tab=questions) tab? This list only goes 60 days back, though.

Comment: @Thisismuchhealthier I checked and it is empty

Comment: Seems I'm okay now -- this question has a positive score!

Comment: Because I upvoted. =)

Comment: Good chance you have asked questions in the past, over 60 days ago, and they were heavily downvoted and deleted. Only a moderator can find them now to confirm this.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I think pacoverflow got it

Comment: @Demetri I doubt it, but only a team member can confirm.

Comment: I know *I* didn't ask any questions on Meta.SE that were downvoted and deleted.

Comment: @pacoverflow but did you ask question on Meta.SO before April (when MSE and MSO were split)?  You old MSO history is part of MSE, not MSO.

Comment: @pacoverflow it's very easy to forget bad things. Part of human nature...

Comment: No I didn't ask any questions on Meta.SO.  They do discourage duplicate questions, so it makes sense for them to include duplicates as part of the formula for determining a questions ban.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I meant that pacoverflow answered my question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's because prior to this question, you had asked 3 questions on Meta.SE, and 2 of them were marked "duplicate".  I encountered the same situation last week - I had asked 3 questions on Meta.SE and 2 of them were marked "duplicate", and when I went to ask a fourth question, the system gave me the warning about a potential question ban.  It's not just downvoted questions that can trigger a question ban, multiple duplicate questions can trigger a ban as well.

Comment: However 2 dups out of 3 questions is not the same degree of offence as say 8 dups out of 12 questions.  And warnings could be a lot more specific.  E.g. you should get a notification that you have too many duplicate questions -- pay more attention to the alternates.